# React Router 4 Warning: "tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on"

Tags: react-router

I can't seem to find a way of making this warning go away.

When the application first loads, the URL only receives the "#/" from hash router, so I've added the conditional `<Redirect />` so that the user gets redirected to the first tab, but this throws the warning message `tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on`.

Does anyone know how to fix this warning?

```
<HashRouter>
<div>

  <div>
    <ol>
      { tabs }      
    </ol>
  </div>


  { routes }
  {
      (location.hash == '' || location.hash == '#/') && 
      <Redirect to={'/' + tabs[0].name} /> 
  }

</div>
</HashRouter>
```

Having the `<Redirect />` before or after { routes } seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to wrap the Routes with a  `<Switch />` component that comes with React Router. No more warning.

```
<HashRouter>
<div>

  <div>
    <ol>
      { tabs }      
    </ol>
  </div>

  <Switch>
    { routes }
    <Redirect to={'/' + tabs[0].name} /> 
  </Switch>

</div>
</HashRouter>
```